# From JSON to CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have been dealing with some data in JSON format; I would like to take both values (answers to two questions that re in the JSON file) provided for each URL and the URL itself and store it in CSV file. However, I wish to have the values (low, medium) in another column, rather than two separate rows below. So, one column has the URL link and another column to have values other two values are related to that URL.

Any help is welcome! Thank you in advance!

Here is the photo of the CSV I have right now:

[image: CSV]

And the code:

```
var1 = []
var2 = []
with open('test3.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
for bill in data:
    var1.append(bill["Labeled Data"])
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([bill["Labeled Data"]])
    for organization in (bill["Label"]['classifications']):
        var2.append(organization['answer']['value'])
        writer.writerow([organization['answer']['value']])
```

Here is how the JSON file that I am trying to get the data from looks like:

```
{"ID":"cksbp3fupbold0yalebil37ec","DataRow ID":"cks3asl3w344l0yuf3bdie3tb","Labeled Data":"https://storage.labelbox.com/cks3ao16d78600ydkaozs0dgb%2F9b4b73c8-9a2e-9edc-d803-9dbcdb61205d-bath_104.jpg?Expires=1631615124231&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-3&Signature=WaMtBsdNYvH31UCbhNg44H_SUXk","Label":{"objects":[],"classifications":[{"featureId":"cksbp4m6e00013f63qv7wlanw","schemaId":"cksbo04d5biaw0yal2lffbdaj","title":"What is the size of bathoom?","value":"what_is_the_size_of_bathoom?","answer":{"featureId":"cksbp4m6e00003f63ogj4n3wb","schemaId":"cksbo04efbib30yalfm9jea4k","title":"Medium","value":"medium"}},{"featureId":"cksbp4s2h00033f63w1lm94p7","schemaId":"cksbo04d6biay0yal2uqu0tzt","title":"What quality is the bathroom?","value":"what_quality_is_the_bathroom?","answer":{"featureId":"cksbp4s2h00023f63vqn95dkg","schemaId":"cksbo04embibd0yal5z2wf2d1","title":"High","value":"high"}}],"relationships":[]},"Project Name":"Orbit","Created At":"2021-08-14T11:28:51.000Z","Updated At":"2021-08-14T11:28:51.473Z","Seconds to Label":32.418,"External ID":"bath_104.jpg","Agreement":-1,"Benchmark Agreement":-1,"Benchmark ID":null,"Dataset Name":"Bathroom","Reviews":[],"View Label":"https://editor.labelbox.com?project=cks3aqbzk7d8r0zd51w7ihjti&label=cksbp3fupbold0yalebil37ec","Has Open Issues":0,"Skipped":false},
```

Comment: Hello! Could you please give more explicit names to `var1` and `var2` so that it's easier to understand your code?

Comment: @Stef those are arrays that I fill with the information from the JSON file that is below

Comment: csv writer writes an array to a file, separating each element with a comma. So the fix is just to append all information to one array, write it to the file and then overwrite the array on the next iteration.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick-fix:

```py
with open('test3.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    for bill in data:
        row = [bill["Labeled Data"]]
        row.extend([organization['answer']['value'] for organization in bill["Label"]['classifications']])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here are the three main changes:

- I moved `writer=csv.writer(csvfile)` to outside of the loop, because there is no need to run it in the loop;
- I added the values `organization['answer']['value']` to the current `row` before calling `writer.writerow(row)`
- I removed `var1` and `var2` because I don't know what they were for.